# Xcode and Unity missing library 'lGoogleUtilities'

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, admob

I am working on an App that is made with Unity and I have to build it in Xcode to get it in the App store.

Now I'm running into a problem here. I am getting this error:

```
library not found for -lGoogleUtilities
```

However, when I build the app in debug mode and test it on my iPad, there aren't any troubles. But when I try to build it for TestFlight (Toolbar -> Product -> Archive) that error occurs.

I've followed this tutorial to get it working in debug mode (because I had that error there too before)
https://youtu.be/YHHj1bZUbsc (from 6:20).

I am using the 'Google Admob', 'CloudOnce' and 'Play Services Resolver' plugins for Unity. In the **debug** version the error (before I fixed it in the **debug** version), was caused by 'Google Admob'. I feel like I am missing a framework or something in the release build.

Comment: I am having the same issue.

Comment: @thirteen4054 I figured it out, You have to open the .xcodeworkspace, not the .xcodeproj file, it should compile then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alright, so after another few hours of trying and searching I found out that I was actually opening the wrong file, you would think `.xcodeproj` would be the correct extension, but actually you have to open the `.xcodeworkspace` file. It compiled for me.