# not found library for -lGoogleUtilities-library

Tags: swift, xcode, admob

I have been building an iOS app with Google AdMob with CocoaPods. Now, I am stuck with the error, "not found library for -lGoogleUtilities-library", for a while. Some people have answered this question before ([Xcode and Unity missing library 'lGoogleUtilities'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58187800/xcode-and-unity-missing-library-lgoogleutilities)), which a developer should open the `.xcodeworkspace` file instead of the `.xcodeproject` file. I know a lot of people solved their issues in this way, but this error still appears in my `.xcodeworkspace` file.

**Supplemental info:**

Swift 4.2

Xcode 10.15.10

**Screenshots:**

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5sHV.png)

[My Link Binary With Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpBs7.png)

[My Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odGkH.png)

Answer (score 1):

The iOS version in my Podfile and it on project were different. I solved this by matching the iOS version in those. Then the error went away.